# C++ OpenCV function "mat.at<Vec3b>(Point(j, i))" not yielding correct pixel values and crashing

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, for-loop, pixel

I am trying to make a simple program that reads the pixel values (BGR) of an input image and makes an output image of the same size but if the pixel in the original picture is white, the output image's pixel (of the same position) is Blue, and if the pixel is not white, makes the same pixel in the output image Black. However I'm having difficulties getting it to work correctly. It seemed pretty easy but it doesn't behave how I'd expect it to. Here's my code for it below:

```
Mat input;
Mat output;
Vec3b color;
input = imread("C:/temp/COLORTEST2.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
output = input;
int rows = input.rows;
int cols = input.cols;
int Blue, Green, Red;
cout << "Rows: " << rows << "\nColumns: " << cols << "\nTotal Pixels: " << (rows*cols) << endl;
cout << "Calculating...\n\n";
for (j = 0; j < rows; j++)
{
    for (i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        color = input.at<Vec3b>(Point(j, i));
        Blue = color.val[0];
        Green = color.val[1];
        Red = color.val[2];

        if (Blue == 255 && Green == 255 && Red == 255){
            W++; //White count +1
            output.at<Vec3b>(Point(j, i))[0] = 255;
            output.at<Vec3b>(Point(j, i))[1] = 0;
            output.at<Vec3b>(Point(j, i))[2] = 0;
        }
        else{
            NW++; //NonWhite count +1
            output.at<Vec3b>(Point(j, i))[0] = 0;
            output.at<Vec3b>(Point(j, i))[1] = 0;
            output.at<Vec3b>(Point(j, i))[2] = 0;
            //cin >> response;
        }

    }
}
cout << "White Pixels: " << W << "\nNon-White Pixels: " << NW << endl;
imwrite("C:/temp/Output.png", output);
waitKey();
```

Like I said, seems simple enough, but it crashes when I run it. If i switch rows and cols in the for loops it runs fine but the output image looks nothing like it should (vertical strips with a few black pixels). The function "mat.at(Point(j, i))" seems to be the problem, looks like it crashes at a certain point, as if its looking for a point that doesn't exist almost as if the rows and columns were switched but that doesn't make sense... I've also tested it by making an MS paint picture (20 x 30) and putting a single black pixel at 1x1 and it said that at 1x1 its BGR was 255, 0, 0... which means it thought it was blue and makes even less sense... I am really stumped and if anyone has any advice on this funtion and how it works I'd be very thankful.

EDIT: Here is the output and input images. This is the error i was talking about, the output is stripped and not even completed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtSRz.jpg
Specs:
Windows 8.1
Visual Studio 2013
OpenCV 2.4.10
C++

Comment: Please share the error message,, the line it crashes.. any information that helps to identify the problem quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code with the sample input image that you provided.Your input image contains alpha channel.So it is a four channel image.you should use `Vec4b` instead of `Vec3b` to get correct result.
Otherwise change the statement 
`input = imread(imgpath, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED)` to `input = imread(imgpath, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)` to load image in 3 channel BGR format and to continue with `Vec3b`.

Comment: Why is point not needed? How does it differ from using it without point? Also, the output image is striped and isnt even completed: http://imgur.com/a/DPRlO

Comment: sorry for inaccurate answer.I edited my answer and provided right solution to the problem you are facing.

Comment: And with using pointer we need to acess the pixel like this..img.at<Vec3b>(Point(col,row)) .Without pointer you can access like this.input.at<Vec3b>((row, col))

Comment: Ahh, I had no idea it was 4 channeled. That fixed the issue, I had no idea that was even a problem... or that it was even 4 channeled to begin with, still new to OpenCV. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
output = input;
```

This is a shallow copy. That means every time you change output data, the data of input will be changed. You should do it like this:

```
output = input.clone();
```

`Point(x,y)` => **x** refers to column and **y** refers to rows. You are doing it reversely.

Change those:

```
for (j = 0; j < rows; j++)
{
    for (i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
```

to those:

```
for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
{
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
```

BTW `BLUE`,`RED`,`GREEN` should be `uchar` rather than `int`.

Comment: So I made the changed you suggested, it works a bit better but the output doesn't really make sense. Here's the input and the output: http://imgur.com/a/DPRlO  
As you can see, there's tons of white lines through it as if it skipped columns and didnt even complete the part on the far right.

Comment: are you sure that pixel are 100% white? they may be 255 254 255 for example.. you should check if BLUE,RED,GREEN are in range of for example 240-255 rather that exactly 255